# Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster) is now released and is no longer off-topic

Tags: discussion, scope

Ubuntu 23.04 (a.k.a. Lunar Lobster) is now released. As of today (April 20th, 2023), posts about it are no longer off-topic on Ask Ubuntu. As usual, posts still must meet [the normal requirements for being on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), though.

Additionally, please refrain from re-opening questions about Ubuntu 23.04 that were posted prior to its release without Meta consensus. They can be re-opened, but it needs to be agreed upon via a Meta discussion first.

See also [the Lunar Lobster Release Notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/lunar-lobster-release-notes/31910)